# Is it a bad practice to define a ViewModel as a DependencyProperty for data-binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel

I have a UserControl MyView, which has an inner UserControl SubView.

The view models of the 2 UserControls have the same hierarchical structure as the views,
i,e, MyViewModel has SubViewModel inside as shown in the code below.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private readonly SubViewModel _subViewModel = new SubViewModel();

    public SubViewModel SubViewModel { get { return _subViewModel; } }

    private void HandleSubViewModel()
    {
        // Do what is necessary to handle SubViewModel
    }
}
```

My question is about how to bind SubViewModel to SubView.

Now I define SubViewModel in the code-behind of SubView and bind it to the SubViewModel property of MyViewModel class.

```
public partial class SubView : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SubViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SubViewModel", typeof (SubViewModel), typeof (SubView), new PropertyMetadata(default(SubViewModel)));

    public SubViewModel SubViewModel
    {
        get { return (SubViewModel) GetValue(SubViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SubViewModelProperty, value); }
    }
}

<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.View.MyView"
             xmlns:parts="clr-namespace:MyProject.View.Parts">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=MyViewModel}">
        <parts:SubView SubViewModel="{Binding SubViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Is it a bad practice to bind an inner view model in this way?

If so, how can I bind it in a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason why it could be bad is that if a property inside the `SubViewModel` changes, there is no way that the `MyViewModel` would know about that. So for e.g. if there are any validations that you need to carry out and handle at the `MyViewModel` level, you would not be able to do that.

To work around that, when a property changes; you would have to raise an event in the `SubViewModel` and make the `MyViewModel` subscribe to it and react appropriately after receiving it.

Apart from that I see no drawbacks as such. But do read these links for further info:
[MVVM and nested view models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366728/mvvm-and-nested-view-models)

[MVVM: How to handle interaction between nested ViewModels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576536/mvvm-how-to-handle-interaction-between-nested-viewmodels)

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift answer. In my actual code, `SubViewModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that it is possible for `MyViewModel` to know the changes of `SubViewModel` properties.

Comment: Yes, why not? Have an Event like `SubViewModelChanged` in the `SubViewModel` and whenever you wish to notify of a property change , raise this event. In the `MyViewModel` simply subscribe to this event and act accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this: 
View models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private readonly SubViewModel _subViewModel;

    public SubViewModel SubViewModel
    {
        get { return _subViewModel; }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        _subViewModel = new SubViewModel();
        _subViewModel.Text1 = "blabla";
    }
}

public class SubViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public string Text1
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Text1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Text1Property, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Text1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text1", typeof(string), typeof(SubViewModel));
}
```

SubUserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.SubUserControl"
         xmlns= ... >
<Grid Height="200" Width="300" Background="Aqua">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubViewModel.Text1}" /> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'd like prevent `SubViewModel` from inheriting `DependencyObject`, since `DependencyObject` has thread affinity.

Comment: No problem. SubViewModel.Text1 does not need to be a dependency property. It can be a normal property when INotifypropertyChanged is implemented.